# View shifts up when textfield is tapped & keyboard appears, even though there is no code to move the view upwards

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

This is a very weird problem that I've been unable to resolve.
I have this `UICollectionViewCell` named as `DownloadUrlCell` with some properties as follows:

```
class DownloadUrlCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .gray
        setupCellView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    //MARK: properties
    let container: UIView = {
        let vi = UIView()
        vi.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vi.backgroundColor = .white
        vi.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        vi.addShadowToSelf()
        return vi
    }()

    let urlInputTF: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        tf.textColor = .black
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        return tf
    }()

    //MARK: setup methods
    func setupCellView() {
        setupContainer()
        addUrlTFAndBtn()
    }

    func setupContainer() {
        self.addSubview(container)

        container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    }

    func addUrlTFAndBtn() {
        //urlInputTF.delegate = self
        container.addSubview(urlInputTF)

        urlInputTF.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        urlInputTF.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        urlInputTF.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        urlInputTF.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }
}
```

The `UICollectionViewCell` (`DownloadUrlCell`) has a container that has a `UITextField` inside it and that all the code to this cell, nothing else.

Now when I tap the textfield the view shifts up by the keyboard's height. **I have not added any code to shift view**. I have no idea why this is happening and could not find any similar questions on stack or anywhere else.
**I have not used any third-party libraries**.

**Edit1**: Okay so, I've uploaded a demo project that has the same issue. The textfield is in the third cell(named: DownloadUrlCell). Below is the link to the github project:

https://github.com/AfnanAhmadiOSDev/VDProjectDemo.git

**Edit2**: So after trying a few other things I've come to the conclusion that the problem exist only in `UICollectionViewCell`. If I add the textfield in any `UIViewController`, it works fine with no problems but if I add the textfield inside a `UICollectionViewCell` and then tap the textfield the view shifts up.

Below is a simple project with `UICollectionViewController` and a simple cell. Nothing else in the project but the problem still remains.

https://github.com/AfnanAhmadiOSDev/VDSimpleDemo

**Edit3**: So after poking around I found this answer that actually helped. However the reason remains unclear.

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980844/10758374

Comment: You have used `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` ?

Comment: No I have not used any external library.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad can you share any demo project where we can look?

Comment: Okay I will try to upload a demo to git and share it here as soon as possible.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I've added the link to the demo project. Please check it and provide any helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 11, there are propertiy to turn off this type of scrolling behaviour.

Add following code in `setupCollectionView()` method to fix your issue.

```
    func setupCollectionView(){

        ....
        ....

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        } else {
            automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the cause of this issue. And you've only provided a solution for ios 11, what about previous OS versions ?

Comment: Check my updated answer, for ios 10 or earlier your can use `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property. Set it to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you have to add this two line in your setupCollectionView()

```
func setupCollectionView(){
    self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .gray
    self.collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
    self.collectionView?.register(HomeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "homecellid")
    self.collectionView?.register(VideoListCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "secondcellid")
    self.collectionView?.register(DownloadUrlCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DownloadUrlCellid")
    self.collectionView?.register(FourthCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FourthCellid")
    self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(65, 0, 0, 0)
    self.collectionView?.bounces = false
    self.collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    } else {
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    }
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Hope this helps :)

Comment: I did exactly this but the issue remained. However I found a solution. The problem was how the main UICollectionViewController was being created. After changing it into a simple UIViewController and then adding a UICollectionView property into that controller made things work fine.

Comment: appreciate the help :)